# Constraint layout setting runtime constraintStart_toEndOf

Tags: android, android-view, android-constraintlayout, android-design-library

I have a constraint 
`app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"`. Runtime I need to change this constraint to `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id\myid"` .

From my research i found only  `constraintSet.connect(viewid, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END, 50);` . But how to achieve my requirements with this. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

This is in `kotlin` but it's barely different from `Java`.

1. Give an ID to the `rootLayout`.
2. Now, use this code:

   ```
   val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
   constraintSet.clone(rootLayout) //Your rootLayout
   constraintSet.connect(
      yourView.id,                //ID of the view whose position you want to change
      ConstraintSet.START,      
      yourMyIdView.id,            //ID of the correspondent view
      ConstraintSet.END
   )
   constraintSet.applyTo(rootLayout) //Your rootLayout
   ```

ProTip : You can also animate the change by setting `animateChange` to `true` in `rootLayout` (XML) or you can use a `Transition` animation which I always prefer.

```
val transition: Transition = ChangeBounds()
transition.interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator() //Or Any other Interpolator
transition.duration = 700 //Duration
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootLayout, transition) //Your rootLayout
constraintSet.applyTo(rootLayout) //Remember to put above 4 lines before this
```

You can further add `Alpha` animation it by using `yourView.animate().alpha(1f).duration = 700 //1f (0 to 1) is the value and 700 is the duration`.

Remember, it is barely different from Java, you just have to add `;` at the end possibly.